# Executeasync in the same method

Tags: windows-phone-7, rest-client

i'm trying to call a restclient in the method including the parsing of data, her's my code which i want to make all of it in the method,any ideas please :

```
 public void Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture){RestClient client = new RestClient();

client.BaseUrl = "http://";

RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.AddParameter("action", "REE");
request.AddParameter("atm_longitude", location.Longitude);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, ParseFeedCallBack_ListDistance);}
public void ParseFeedCallBack_ListDistance(IRestResponse response){
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    ParseXMLFeedDistance(response.Content);
}
private string ParseXMLFeedDistance(string feed)
{
.... return myvalueToBind;
}
```

Comment: Like I said earlier, **don't** call asynchronous methods in converter functions. Call them in your view model when you know you need it.

Comment: hello, i did somthing like this:

Answer (score 0):

i did somthing like this,but it don't call ParseXMLFeedDistance for every item :

```
 foreach (var resp in xmlItems2.Descendants("result"))
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient();
                client.BaseUrl = "http://";

                RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

                request.Method = Method.GET;
                request.AddParameter("action", "atms_distances");

                request.AddParameter("lang", "ar");
                request.AddParameter("mode", "xml");
                request.AddParameter("appli", "WP");
                request.AddParameter("mobile_latitude", "35.843283");
                request.AddParameter("mobile_longitude", "10.61617");
                request.AddParameter("atm_latitude", resp.Element("Lattitude"));
                request.AddParameter("atm_longitude",resp.Element("longitude"));
               // client.ExecuteAsync(request, ParseFeedCallBack_ListDistance);
                client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {
                    ParseXMLFeedDistance(response.Content);
                });
            }
 private void ParseXMLFeedDistance(string feed)
    {
        if (feed == null)
            return;
        try
        {
            XElement xmlItems = XElement.Parse(feed);

            XDocument xmlItems2 = XDocument.Parse(feed);

            var list = new List<State>();
            foreach (XElement val in xmlItems2.Descendants("result").Last().Elements())
            {

              //  distance = val.Value;
                list.Add(new State
                {
                    TotalDistance = val.Value,
                });
            }
            ResultSearch_ListDistance.ItemsSource = list;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```